# jquery .html Works only with internet explorer debugger enabled

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer

This works in firefox and chrome but only works if I have the debugger enabled in IE 11, just a simple example that should replace the word 'TEST' with a random number and change the random number with each click.  With IE debugger disabled it displays a random number from the .get and stops.   With IE debugger enabled I get a new random number with every click.  Help!

```
<head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $(".favtoggle").click(function() {
        id = $(this).attr('id');
        $.get("/testtoggle.php?id="+id, function(data, status) {
          $("#" + id).html(data);
          //alert("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);
        });
      });
    });
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="favtoggle" id="test">
    <font size=+2>test</font>
  </div>
</body>
```

testtoggle.php:

```
<?
  echo rand(0,1000);
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably due to caching...

Try:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
  cache: false
});
```

Comment: that fixed it!   Thanx!

Comment: Good! So please click the green check mark,  aside the voting system, to accept the answer. ;)